# How to automatically install required linux OS packages before using the app?

Tags: linux, electron

I wonder how to tell an ElectronJS app, built only for multi-distro Linux (deployed as Flatpak), to verify and automatically install required OS packages, and then call them via `spawn`. I'd like to prevent it from telling users to manually install them.

Comment: Can this help ? https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution

Comment: Not a chance to make Electron invoke apt-get install?

Comment: You don't want to do that as `apt-get` requires `root` privilege.

Comment: But it already requires root permissions to function, at least as an AppImage file.

Comment: Why not do exactly as you say and use Node.js `spawn` to invoke an `apt-get install`?

Comment: Yes, I used `spawn`, but only if I boot AppImage with `sudo`. I expected it to preinstall them before showing the window, but it's alright, it's solved.